# GRUB does not listlen to input devices (keyboard)

Tags: grub2, keyboard

I've got Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7 installed on my laptop. I've never had any problems with anything related GRUB or the OSs (at least not something strange that I cannot fix).

Well, GRUB went crazy, 30% of the times I start my laptop, it stops to read from the keyboard.
I mean, I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> / <kbd>Arrow</kbd> / <kbd>E</kbd> but it does not react. I guess something like keyboard driver is not doing its job. It wait 10 seconds and load Ubuntu.(Yes it wait 10 sec like always and load Ubuntu the way it should).
70% of the time, however, it is working perfect. I really can't catch when. Why it stop working?

I tried refreshing the GRUB (reinstalling), but it didn't work. Still the same once it work, once it doesn't.

Sorry if you had problems understanding this. I'm no native english speaker.

Comment: I noticed the same thing when I plug my keyboard into a external usb hub, but you are probably using the keyboard of your laptop so that won't be the problem... a sort of workaround could be to [install grub customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer) and set the timeout to a shorter time.

Comment: I have the SAME problem, and what's worse it just started to happen after a few weeks after I installed Ubuntu, so the GRUB. Fixed it, @Nickie?
Why would that be a solution, @Wouter?

Comment: Did you ever do any GRUB update?

Comment: @Diego, it is not a good solution, it only helps that you don't need to wait for 10 seconds to continue to boot.